# Macro fails for large sets of items

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a functioning macro that fails at seemingly random points when running on a large number of items. The macro is used to loop through an inbox folder that receives error logs, save the error log text files, copy specified lines of text from the attachments (error operation names and such), place these strings in an excel file to track them, and then move the email items to another inbox folder once processed. It works great when it goes through less than hundred emails but above that it gets strange. In testing its failed on the 122nd iteration, 648, 350, etc. The general structure is below.

```
Sub ErrorLogAuto()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim TimeInfo As String
Dim SubjectInfo As String
Dim IdNumber As String
Dim Dataline As String

Dim oItem As Object
Dim Item As Outlook.Items
Dim myAttachment(1000) As Outlook.Attachments
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector

Dim appExcel As Object

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim found As Integer
Dim found1 As Integer
Dim found2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim op As Integer
Dim us As Integer
Dim cdata As Integer

i = 0
k = 1

'Returns proper SOURCE folder
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders("Test") '--> text between "" is the folder name, only change it here

'set path for attachments to be saved in
Path = "C:\test\"

'Set item = to all emails in test folder
Set Item = myNewFolder.Items

'If no emails...
If Item.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no error messages to sift through."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Open an instance of excel to certain workbook
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Visible = True
'appExcel.Workbooks.Open (Path & "test.xlsx")
appExcel.Workbooks.Open (Path & "SAMPLE FILE NAME.xlsx")

'Find first empty cell to write to --> based off of column D
While appExcel.Range("D" & k) <> ""
    k = k + 1
Wend

'For every email in folder...here starts the big loop
For Each oItem In Item

    'Save attachment and set filename
    Set myAttachment(i) = oItem.Attachments
        myAttachment(i).Item(1).SaveAsFile Path & myAttachment(i).Item(1).DisplayName & ".txt"
        FileName = Path & myAttachment(i).Item(1).DisplayName & ".txt"

    'Subject and time info
    SubjectInfo = oItem.Subject
    TimeInfo = oItem.ReceivedTime

    'Returns ID number from subject string after '@'
    j = InStr(SubjectInfo, "@")
    IdNumber = Mid(SubjectInfo, j + 1)

    'Write IdNumber to cell and timestamp
    appExcel.Range("A" & k) = TimeInfo
    appExcel.Range("D" & k) = IdNumber


    'Open the notepad file, read line by line until EOF, take user message, and take operation name
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum

    While Not EOF(FileNum)

        Line Input #FileNum, Dataline

        'If string found these will <> 0
        found = InStr(Dataline, "<OperationName>")
        found1 = InStr(Dataline, "<UserMessage>")
        found2 = InStr(Dataline, "<UserMessage><![CDATA[")

        'Returns position right after where string is found
        op = InStr(Dataline, "<OperationName>") + 15
        us = InStr(Dataline, "<UserMessage>") + 13
        cdata = InStr(Dataline, "<UserMessage><![CDATA[") + 22

        'Found operation name line
        If found <> 0 Then
            'appExcel.Range("B1") = Dataline --> whole line
            'appExcel.Range("C" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, 20), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, 20)) - 16) --> doesnt account for whitespace
            appExcel.Range("N" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, op), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, op)) - 16) '--> accounts for whitespace and cuts out <OperationName> and <\OperationName>
        'Found user message line and it includes cdata stuff
        ElseIf found1 <> 0 And found2 <> 0 Then
            'appExcel.Range("C1") = Dataline --> whole line
            'appExcel.Range("D" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, 20), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, 20)) - 14) --> doesnt account for whitespace
            'appExcel.Range("O" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, us), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, us)) - 14) --> accounts for whitespace and cuts out <UserMessage> and <\UserMessage>
            appExcel.Range("O" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, cdata), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, cdata)) - 17) '--> accounts for whitespace and cuts out <UserMessage><![CDATA[ and ]]><\UserMessage>
        'Found user message line WITHOUT cdata stuff
        ElseIf found1 <> 0 Then
            appExcel.Range("O" & k) = Mid(Mid(Dataline, us), 1, Len(Mid(Dataline, us)) - 14) '--> accounts for whitespace and cuts out <UserMessage> and <\UserMessage>
        End If

    Wend

    Close #FileNum

    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1

Next

Call FolderMove


End Sub

Private Sub FolderMove()

    Dim a As MailItem
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim Source As MAPIFolder
    Dim Destination As MAPIFolder

    Set Source = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Source = Source.Folders("Test") '--> text between "" is the folder name, only change it here

    Set Destination = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Destination = Destination.Folders("Testing Done") '--> text between "" is the folder name, only change it here

    For m = Source.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set a = Source.Items(m)
        a.move Destination
    Next

End Sub
```

The code breaks down while reading the file in the not EOF loop. Are these errors caused by bad programming practices? I've never worked with large sets before and am new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Error information: Run-time error '50290': Application-defined or object defined error. --> occured on 363rd iteration

Restarted at debug and got to 540 before failing in the same way.

Then I restarted and it finished ok.

So now my question is why does this happen?

Comment: it's hard to say if it's bad practice when we don't have the full source. But unless you have REALLY big instances or if you are trying to compile some data about all the items as a whole, it _probably_ isn't bad practice.

Comment: Is the excel file in a shared folder?

Comment: no its a local copy

Comment: When the program stop and enter the debuger. Can you just restart from where you left(ie. just pressing f5 again makes it work)

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: Posting the whole code would help! The structure you put right there isn't problematic by itself.

Comment: Also, how does it fail. do you have an error code?

Comment: You don't really have a choice right now, unless you can spot the block that fails

Comment: In terms of how it fails, I think it was an exception error. And I did not think to try running it again once the debugger opened. I'll rerun for a large number of items to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an online profile (as opposed to cached), Exchange will limit the number off items you can open (250 by default. You need to make sure you explicitly release the objects by setting them to Northing (VBA) or calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject in .Net. You should also make sure you do not use multipole dot notation to avoid implicit variable that you cannot explicitly release.

```
for i = 1 to Item.Count
  set oItem = Item.Items(i)
  set oAttachments = oItem.Attachments
  if oAttachments.Count > 0 Then
    set oAttachment = oAttachments.Item(1) ' do you really want a loop through all attachments?
    FileName = Path & oAttachment.FileName
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile FileName
    set oAttachment = Nothing
  End If
  ...
  set oAttachments = Nothing
  set oItem = Nothing 
Next i
```